# Array build with map returning `undefined` when selecting element attribute

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array with only the attribute `data-id` of each elements but getting an `undefined` array. What am I doing wrong ?

The declaration:
`var list = [...document.querySelectorAll("#selection > tr")].map(el => el["data-id"]);`

The elements:

```
<tbody id="selection">
  {% for form in formset %}
    <tr data-id={{form.instance.id}}>
    </tr>
  {% endfor%}
</tbody>
```

thank you

Comment: use `getAttribute("data-id")`

Comment: Excellent, thank you !

Comment: i've put it as an answer

Comment: [Datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) might be more appropriate, e.g. `element.dataset[keyname]` (or `el => el.dataset.id` in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-*` attributes are accessed in JS code using `.dataset.*` (in your case `.dataset.id`)

final code should be

```
var list = [...document.querySelectorAll("#selection > tr")].map(el => el.dataset.id);
```

check out [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

Answer (score 1):

`var list = [...document.querySelectorAll("#selection > tr")].map(el => el.getAttribute("data-id"));`